# how to pipe a file from an s3 bucket to cat?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have access to an s3 bucket whose content I can easily list in the terminal using:

```
aws s3 ls "s3://mybucket/myfiles/file_001.gz"
```

I am trying to pipe these files to `gzip` for unzipping on the fly, so that I can quickly open one and look at it using `nano` or `cat`.

However, doing the following does not work

```
aws s3 ls "s3://mybucket/myfiles/file_001.gz" | xargs gunzip -c | nano
```

I wonder if I a missing a piped command that would download the file from the s3 locally before piping to `gunzip`. Not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/object.gz - | gunzip -c | nano` ?

Comment: What's wrong with the current command? Any errors?

Comment: @AnonCoward what does the `-` do after `cp`? Thanks!

Comment: If `-` is provided as the target, then output is sent to stdout. If `-` is provided as the source, then input is read from stdin. See: [AWS Command line: S3 content from stdin or to stdout](https://loige.co/aws-command-line-s3-content-from-stdin-or-to-stdout/)